# Grove Pi+ Multichannel Gas Sensor Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, grovepi+

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B model with a Grove Pi+ (1.2.2 firmware), and Raspbian for Robots Image.
I am plug-in the Multichannel Gas Sensor in I2C-1 port, and I am trying to execute the code that is [available in Dexter´s Github](https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/blob/master/Software/Python/grove_i2c_multichannel_gas_sensor/multichannel_gas_sensor.py). I am getting the following issues:

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Desktop/GrovePi/Software/Python/grove_i2c_multichannel_gas_sensor/multichannel_gas_sensor.py",
> line 85, in m= MutichannelGasSensor() File
> "/home/pi/Desktop/GrovePi/Software/Python/grove_i2c_multichannel_gas_sensor/multichannel_gas_sensor.py",
> line 39, in init if self.readR0() >= 0: File
> "/home/pi/Desktop/GrovePi/Software/Python/grove_i2c_multichannel_gas_sensor/multichannel_gas_sensor.py",
> line 45, in readR0 rtnData = self.readData(0x11) File
> "/home/pi/Desktop/GrovePi/Software/Python/grove_i2c_multichannel_gas_sensor/multichannel_gas_sensor.py",
> line 70, in readData buffer=bus.read_i2c_block_data(self.address, cmd,
> 4)IOError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

When I was running the old firmware of GrovePi+, this error was not appearing, but it was not working, nothing appears on screen.

Checking the code line by line, I realize that in line 71 is print(data), after the buffer=bus.read_i2c_block_data(self.address, cmd, 4), but "data" variable is not defined in the code. Something is strange in this code.

Can someone help me with this grove pi sensor? Can someone give me any hint?

Comment: probably you havent permission related port. and need check every port/cable for right connection/publishing to external service. A litlle trick when used a communication based equpments initial ceck port accessible and default setting. Github not a software provider and a lot package is very sample so don't need any module, you can write it !  Otherwise you wasted a lot time for fixin 3rd software !

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of problems that we had encountered when porting the code for the sensor.It was on the same I2C address as the GrovePi and the data returned from it was not consistent. Hence the Sensor does not work right now with the GrovePi and the code work is still  in progress, this might take some time to get this done.

-Shoban